# How to disable combo box on first form by clicking save on the second form

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I would like to disable the combo box which was in the first Form on clicking save on the second Form.

I am having 2 forms and my requirement is to append the 2 forms data together this was done

For my requirement i write a small code but it doesn't work for me

My code is as follows

Form1 i write my code as follows

```
   public void loadingDatafrom(bool str)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            cmbServiceClassCode.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cmbServiceClassCode.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Form2 after save and hiding the form2 i call the above method

```
      frmBatch frmbatch = new frmBatch(frmmain);
    frmbatch.loadingDatafrom(true);
```

But this is not working any help please.

Comment: you have to send reference of Form1 to Form2.... Then by using reference you can use any control on first form....

Comment: Could you please in detail describe how it is not working?

Comment: Does my code make sense for what i am trying

Comment: @Pieter i think as i declared new form it is not giving me the correct output i need

Comment: Do you do `frmBatch frmbatch = new frmBatch(frmmain);` all the time?

Comment: Not all the time after saving the 2nd form data i did this

Comment: what i need is i would like to show the data as it is on the form1 and make only the combobox as non editable field

Comment: @Dorababu I guess your problem is that you create new `frmBatch` instead of reusing an old instance. But you´re only posting code fragments. That makes it hard to tell. You need to be more specific about when you instantiate your forms, which form that has references to which. And if Form1 is frmBatch and Form2 is frmmain or the other way around.

Comment: My main form is FrmBatch and on this i will have a combobox and my 2nd form name is Frmentry on this form if i click on save i will hide this form and i did not write any code to show the frmBatch as i will have some data in text boxes and i want to show that data as it is by disabling the combo box with the previous selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question. From your main form FrmBatch, Call the 2nd form FrmEntry in modal mode. After you Save and close FrmEntry form, you have to disabled combox box. In FrmBatch call this :

```
Form2 FrmEntry = new Form2();
FrmEntry.ShowDialog();

cmbServiceClassCode.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I think in a foolish way why i forgot this till i did not understand any way thanks Robert

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to fix is

<strike>`if (true)`</strike> ->  `if (str)`

Comment: @Pieter - Ya i know that i just tried that if the above is not working